# initiate browser in PHP like ROR

Tags: php, ruby, browser

Ruby provides us methotds to initiate browser, open url in that browser and parse the page contents

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox)
browser.goto("http://example.com")
browser.wait

results = browser.text

parsed_results = JSON.parse(results)
```

Can we do such a thing in PHP? If yes then how it is possible?

Comment: if the goal is to fetch some page contents, then there is an easier way to do it in PHP than with a virtual browser. Is that what you want?

Comment: http://www.simpletest.org/en/browser_documentation.html

Comment: @JanDvorak yes i want to fetch the content. but that page is password protected. I have to login in that page with browser. Ruby allows ths

Comment: "password protected" normally means you have to send the right headers or the right cookies. The former shouldn't be difficult, and CUrl might help with the latter, too. The problem description (access a password-protected page (which kind of password protection does it use?)) should be in the question itself, however.